# Converting sets into intervals with variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, notation, absolute-value

I am trying to convert the set to interval form where center is $c$ and the radius is $r$. I have not had any problem doing the first example but I cannot find a way to get the $c$ value for the second question. How would I be able to solve the $c$ for the second question as well as turning it into interval notation?

> 1. $ \left|x^2 - 1\right| > 2 $
> 2. $ \left|x^2 - 2x\right| > 2 $

**Work**

1. $ \left|x^2 - 1\right| > 2 $

$c= 1$ and $r = 2$
$$(-\infty, \sqrt{c-r})\cup(\sqrt{c+r}, +\infty)$$
$$(-\infty, \sqrt{1-2})\cup(\sqrt{1+2}, +\infty)$$
$$(-\infty, \sqrt{-1})\cup(\sqrt3, +\infty)$$
So the intervals are between $(-\infty, -\sqrt3)\cup(\sqrt3, +\infty)$ for example 1.

2. $ \left|x^2 - 2x\right| > 2 $

$c = ?$ and $r = 2$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the formulas in your MSE posts. Apart from that, it is very unclear what you are asking. In your first example, you have correctly identified the two intervals whose union is $\{x \mid |x^2 - 1| > 2\}$. But those intervals are infinite, so they don't have a centre and a radius.

Answer (score 1):

It is ideal to solve these problems directly.

**First problem**

Note that for the first problem, you have to find all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$ |x^2 -1| > 2 \tag{1}$$

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$ be a real number that satisfies (1). By definition of the modulus sign, this condition is equivalent to the statement that
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
&x^2 - 1 > 2 \tag{1a}\\
\text{or } &x^2 - 1 < -2. \tag{1b}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
What remains is for us to solve each of these inequalities, and find all the real values that satisfy (1a) or (1b). Indeed, all the $x$ values that satisfy (1a) are such that
$$
x^2 > 3 \quad \iff \quad x > \sqrt{3} \text{ or }x<-\sqrt{3}. 
$$
Regarding the second inequality (1b) $ x^2 < -1 $, no real number satisfies this constraint, and thus the only real values that satisfy the initial inequality $|x^2 - 1| > 2$ are such that $x\in(-\infty,-\sqrt{3})\cup(\sqrt{3},\infty)$, i.e.

$$
|x^2 - 1| > 2 \quad \iff \quad x\in(-\infty,-\sqrt{3})\cup(\sqrt{3},\infty).
$$

**Second problem:**

For the second problem, one needs simply to apply the same procedure. We have to find all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
|x^2 - 2x| > 2. \tag{2}
$$
Assume that $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is a real number that satisfies (2). Then by definition of the modulus sign, (2) is equivalent that $x$ satisfies either of the following conditions:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
&x^2 - 2x > 2 \tag{2a} \\
\text{or } &x^2 - 2x < -2. \tag{2b}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Solving the first inequality (2a), we find that
$$
x^2 - 2x > 2 \quad \iff \quad (x - 1)^2  > 3 \quad \iff \quad x-1 > \sqrt{3} \text{ or } x - 1 < -\sqrt{3}
$$
That is, $x > 1 + \sqrt{3}$ or $x < 1 - \sqrt{3}$.

A similar approach can be done for the second inequality (2b). Indeed, we need to find all the $x$ reals such that
$$
x^2 - 2x < -2.
$$
Indeed, we have that
$$
x^2 - 2x < -2 \quad \iff \quad x^2 - 2x + 2 < 0 \quad \iff \quad (x-1)^2 + 1 < 0,
$$
but this is a sum of two positive real numbers, and so no real numbers that satisfy this second inequality exist.

In conclusion, we have that
$$
|x^2 - 2x| > 2 \quad \iff \quad x\in(-\infty,1-\sqrt{3})\cup(1+\sqrt{3},\infty).
$$

Comment: Upon doing the second question again I found that $ x < 1 - \sqrt{3} $ and $ x > 1+ \sqrt{3} $ were the right answers I got.

Comment: @MasterSelcuk Yes, I corrected the typo now and have expanded upon the answer. Hope this is helpful.